# How to set light theme as default during development environment?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is is possible to set a light theme during development time in Visual studio for Windows Phone. I can only use the dark theme now. Please assist.

[image]

Comment: You mean the theme for the Windows phone emulator or theme of the visual studio?

Comment: @nkchandra: The theme for the design view in the xaml. See the screenshot attached.

Comment: To set the theme in your emulator go to Settings and then Theme. You can toggle between light and dark themes there.

Comment: @KenCenerelli: I know that.. i don't want to launch the emulator. what i am asking is how do you it during the dev time itself ?

Comment: My pc does not support VT and therefor no emulator. So I have to test it on my wp8.1 device. The preview in vs2013 also does not switch the theme. isn't there a workaround available in 2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present there is no way to change the designer in Visual Studio to use the light theme, however if you open your project in Expression Blend (Project|Open in Expression Blend...) there is a Device tab which you can change from Dark to Light and change the accent colour for the designer.

Ref:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff979330(v=Expression.40).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way doing that.

But Hopefully, you can achieve the same in Expression Blend.
Open your XAML in Blend,then In the Device panel:
    In Theme section, You can preview the background theme of the application page by clicking Preview Dark Theme  or Preview Light Theme .